# Compare and return boolean if two array of objects has the values or not

Tags: javascript, reactjs, lodash

I have two array of objects which are like,

```
let A = [{id: "1"}, {id: "2"},{id: "3" }]

let B = [{id: "3"}, {id: "2"}]
```

Now, I am iterating over `A`.

```
return _.map(A) => ({
    id: A.id,
    isAvaliable: //This needs to be like weather B includes A on the basis of ID , means does B object has this A client ID if yes then set it true or false
})
```

So, final object which I will get will be,

```
const result = [{
{id: "1", isavaliable: false},
{id: "2", isavaliable: true},
{id: "3", isavaliable: true},

}
]
```

So, How do I achieve this ?
Thanks.

Comment: your final result is wrong.. please verify. It should be object of array.

Answer (score 1):

First make an array or Set of the `B` ids, then you can `.map` A and set `isavailable` by whether the id is included in the set:

```js
const A = [{id: "1"}, {id: "2"},{id: "3" }];
const B = [{id: "3"}, {id: "2"}];
const haveIds = new Set(B.map(({ id }) => id));

const result = A.map(({ id }) => ({ id, isavailable: haveIds.has(id) }));
console.log(result);
```

No need to rely on an external library, `Array.prototype.map` works just fine.

Comment: Yeah but I was trying to do it in one line so that I can return boolean for this . here in this solution we are rreturning the array again

Answer (score 1):

```js
let A = [{ id: "1" }, { id: "2" }, { id: "3" }];

let B = [{ id: "3" }, { id: "2" }];

const merge = (arr1, arr2) =>
  arr1.map((a) => ({
    id: a.id,
    isAvaliable: !!arr2.find((b) => b.id === a.id),
  }));
console.log(merge(A, B));
```

Answer (score 1):

Use lodash 'find' to check id in array B

```
const A = [{id: '1'}, {id: '2'}, {id: '3' }];
const B = [{id: '3'}, {id: '2'}];

const C = _.map(A, item => {

        return {
            id: item.id,
            isAvailable: _.find(B, {id: item.id}) ? true : false
        };
    });
```